# PowerShell text output vs. console output

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm building a script to monitor my event logs.  This command gathers only "Error" and "Warning" messages and places them into the $entries array.

```
$entries = $log.Entries |
? {$_.TimeWritten -gt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-2)) -and `
(($_.EntryType -like "Error") -or `
($_.EntryType -like "Warning"))} |
Format-Table -wrap
```

If I output $entries in the console, it displays what I want - the log entries - but if I pipe this out to a text file (Add-Content $output $entries) I get the .NET class name only (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry).  I have also tried foreach ($entry in $entries) with similar results.

What's the basic PowerShell principle I'm missing here?

Comment: Not really an answer, but might help you: bear in mind powershell pipes objects (.net objects), NOT text like the bash and co of old. You are actually piping the objects (hense why you are getting the output you are) and need to convert this into the text you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically - the add-content/set-content command just do a ToString() on whatever you pass to it. For many .NET objects, that is just the class name.

If you do:
out-string -inputobject $entries | add-content "yourfile.txt"

That should properly convert to a string and output it to your text file.

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks for the very useful tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add-content will give you this behavior, if you want the fields rather than the object description then the simplest approach is to just use traditional file redirection e.g.

```
$entries > $output
```

or

```
$entries >> $output
```

if you want to append. This works as I would expect it to for your example code while your example of

```
Add-Content $output $entries
```

Only outputs the object type description (e.g. Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData ) for me.

Comment: You know, I tried this and it didn't behave the way I expected it to.  These commands did not add anything to my text file for some reason.

Comment: Interesting - I just checked on another system and it does work as expected for me, very strange. Get-Host tells me I'm running V1.0.0.0, on Vista in both cases. At least Mattb's suggestion worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Piping via:    | Add-Content $output

does not appear to work well, when the content being piped contains numerous lines.

For example:

```
$output = "C:\temp\test.txt" 
$TimeStamp = Get-Date; "STARTED: " + $TimeStamp | Out-File $output -width 800
Get-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" | Add-Content $output
```

In the above example, the test.txt file gets properly created, including the opening comment. However, the Get-ItemProperty output appears as Chinese characters.